# Unexpected result from Calabash using query command

Tags: android, genymotion, calabash, calabash-android

I have just started using Calabash and I am trying to test an Android app running under Genymotion.

When I run the simple test to start the application and view the initial screen, I can see the screen display in the Genymotion emulator but when I use the query command

```
puts(query('*'))
```

I dont see any of the expected content (for example the screen header) in the returned result.

Instead I see only:

```
[{"id"=>nil, "enabled"=>true, "contentDescription"=>nil, "visible"=>true, "tag"=>nil, "description"=>"com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52824ec0 V.E..... R
....... 0,0-1080,1920}", "class"=>"com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView", "rect"=>{"center_y"=>960, "center_x"=>540, "height"=>1920, "y"=>0, "width"=>1080, "x"=>0}}
, {"id"=>nil, "enabled"=>true, "contentDescription"=>nil, "visible"=>true, "tag"=>nil, "description"=>"android.widget.LinearLayout{528127a0 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1080,1920}", "class"
=>"android.widget.LinearLayout", "rect"=>{"center_y"=>960, "center_x"=>540, "height"=>1920, "y"=>0, "width"=>1080, "x"=>0}}, {"id"=>"content", "enabled"=>true, "contentDescription"=>
nil, "visible"=>true, "tag"=>nil, "description"=>"android.widget.FrameLayout{5280cab8 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1080,1920 #1020002 android:id/content}", "class"=>"android.widget.FrameLay
out", "rect"=>{"center_y"=>960, "center_x"=>540, "height"=>1920, "y"=>0, "width"=>1080, "x"=>0}}, {"id"=>"NoResourceEntry-100", "enabled"=>true, "contentDescription"=>"Web View", "vi
sible"=>true, "tag"=>nil, "description"=>"org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView{52821914 VFEDH.C. .F...... 0,0-1080,1920 #64}", "class"=>"org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView", 
"rect"=>{"center_y"=>960, "center_x"=>540, "height"=>1920, "y"=>0, "width"=>1080, "x"=>0}}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the layout of the Android app that was generated by Cordova.  Cordova displays everything from your app inside the SystemWebView, so you want to look in there to find your HTML.  You can see the html of the whole page in the web view with this query

```
query("SystemWebView css:'*'")
```

See [this wiki page](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/06-webview-support) for more detail on how to test web views with Calabash.

Comment: That definitely solved it. Thanks. But does that mean that all of the canned steps for calabash-android eg assert_steps dont work? That was my original problem.

Comment: I was using the "Then I see the text" step which ends up calling 

 query("* {text CONTAINS[c] '<text_to_search_for>'}")

in wait_for_text method.

From what you say this should be:

 query("SystemWebView css:'* {text CONTAINS[c] '<text_to_search_for>'}'")

although I dont really understand how this would be quoted?

Comment: > Canned steps.   Correct. They will not work.  You should write your own steps.

Comment: So if I write the query myself to search for the word Schools on the screen by doing:
```query("SystemWebView css:'* {text CONTAINS[c] \"Schools\"}'")```

I get

```SystemWebView css:'* {text CONTAINS[c] \'Schools\'}', query failed because: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException```

I dont have any clue why this is the case because I was previously getting 'invalid query' which is now not the case?

Comment: query("SystemWebView css:'*' {textContent CONTAINS[c] \"Schools\"}")